# React Modal Dialog appearing only while inspection

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I am new to react and I am using a `modal dialog`. It is visible when I am inspecting it on browser but not visible generally. What could be the issue?
(Can't paste code since it is work related)

Comment: you can create a sample snippet for reproducing the issue, so it will be helpful to answer it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using css z-index at all ? I would use createPortal() approach see the React docs to learn how to do that https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html